# What is an approximation for the B-field of a bar magnet?

Tags: magnetic-fields

I've found the following equation in this [source](http://dmr-physicsnotes.blogspot.de/2013/01/magnetic-field-strength-at-point-due-to.html):
$$B_\text{N,S} = \frac{\mu m}{4\pi r_\text{N,S}^2}$$
Where $r$ is the distance of "one pole"? I do not get how this can be well defined. The effective field is then something like 
$$ B_{\text{eff}} = B_\text{N} - B_\text{S} .$$
Where $\text{S}$ is the south pole and $\text{N}$ the north pole.

I thought that the equation [magnetic dipole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_dipole) would be the starting point for the derivation of the above formula - but I dont see how this formula can be transformed:
$$\vec{B} = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\left(\frac{3\vec{r}(\vec{m}\vec{r})}{r^5} - \frac{\vec{m}}{r^3}\right)$$
The magnitude $B$ is 
$$B = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\left(\frac{3m\cos(\alpha)}{r^3} - \frac{m}{r^3}\right).$$
Are $B_\text{eff}$ and $B$ equivalent?